# How can I show the user is still Pending (not active yet)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, crud, mern

I created logged in form wherein it will pop-out a `toastify` when logged in correctly. So my problem right now is I have a logic wherein the user can only access the website when his account is `active`, but my toastify is not popping correctly. I'm using reduxjs/toolkit my state.

So what I'm trying to achieve here:

1.) Show an `error message` if the account is not existing or wrong password

2.) Show `Account still pending` if the user correctly input his username and password but still not `active`

3.) Navigate to login page when account is active

**api/login.js**

```
const login = async (req,res, next) =>{
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({studentNumber: req.body.studentNumber})
        if(!user) return next(createError(404, "User not found!"))

        const isPasswordCorrect = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)
        if(!isPasswordCorrect) return next(createError(400,"Wrong password or Username!"))

        const accessToken = jwt.sign({id: user._id, isAdmin: user.isAdmin},  'secretkey')

        const {password, ...others} = user._doc
        
        if(others.status === 'active'){
            res.status(200).json({...others, accessToken})
        }
        else{
         next(createError(203, "Account is still pending.."))
        }     

    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
}
```

**authSlice.js**

```
const authSlice = createSlice({
name: 'auth',
initialState: {
    currentUser: null,
    isFetching : false,
    isError: false,
    isSuccess: false,
    message: ''
},
reducers: {
    resetState: (state) =>{
        state.currentUser = null;
        state.isFetching = false
        state.isError = false
        state.isSuccess = false

    },
    loginStart: (state)=>{
        state.isFetching = true;
        state.isError = false;
    },
    loginSuccess: (state, action) =>{
        state.isFetching = true;
        state.isSuccess = true;
        state.currentUser = action.payload
        state.message = action.payload

    },
    loginFailure: (state, action) =>{
        state.isSuccess = false;
        state.isFetching = false;
        state.isError = true;
        state.message = action.payload
    }, 
}

})
```

In authSlice.js, I have a problem that it automatically run the loginFailure, even though the user correctly input it's credential.

apiCall.js

```
const loginUser = async (user, dispatch) => {
  dispatch(loginStart());
  try {
    const res = await publicRequest.post("/auth/login", user);
    dispatch(loginSuccess(res.data));
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch(loginFailure());
  }
};
```

Login.jsx

```
  const {isError, currentUser, message} = useSelector((state) => state.auth)

  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const navigate = useNavigate()


  const {register, handleSubmit, formState: {errors}} = useForm({
    studentNumber: '',
    password: ''
  })
  

  const onSubmit = ({studentNumber,password}) =>{
    let user ={studentNumber, password}
    loginUser(user,dispatch)
  }

  useEffect(() =>{
    if(isError){
      toast.error(message)
    }
    dispatch(resetState())
  },[dispatch, isError])

  useEffect(() =>{
    if(currentUser){
      toast.success(message)
    }
  },[dispatch, currentUser])
```

Login.jsx

```
const Login () =>{
const {isError, currentUser, message} = useSelector((state) => state.auth)

  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const navigate = useNavigate()


  const {register, handleSubmit, formState: {errors}} = useForm({
    studentNumber: '',
    password: ''
  })
  

  const onSubmit = ({studentNumber,password}) =>{
    let user ={studentNumber, password}
    loginUser(user,dispatch)
  }

  useEffect(() =>{
    if(isError){
      toast.error(message)
    }
    dispatch(resetState())
  },[dispatch, isError])

  useEffect(() =>{
    if(currentUser){
      toast.success(message)
    }
  },[dispatch, currentUser])

   return (
   <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
       <TextField name="studentNumber" {...register('studentNumber)} type="text" />
       <TextField name="password" {...register('password)} type="password" />
    </form>

)
}
```

**EDIT
Please ignore the form field if I type it wrong, I just copy paste it and missed something**

Comment: The `{...register('studentNumber)}` and `{...register('password)}` expressions are not properly formatted. They should be wrapped in curly braces

Answer (score 0):

In `apiCall.js`, don't just do `dispatch(loginFailure());`, instead inspect the response and if it has the 203 status code, dispatch the action differently. Maybe login failure, but with a payload that signals to your reducer that the user has logged in successfully, but their account is not active yet.

You probably also want to add another boolean flag to your state, something like `state.auth.isActive`, that is only `true` if the user account is not pending anymore. Or alternatively, if `state.auth.currentUser` is an object with more info, maybe the active/pending flag is contained in there already (in this case don't duplicate it).